# SQL Server recent rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm sure this is easy but I have googled a lot and searched.

Ok, I have a table WITHOUT dates etc with 100000000000000000 records.

I want to see the latest entries, i.e.

```
Select top 200 * 
from table
```

BUT I want to see the latest entries. Is there a rowidentifier that I could use in a table?

ie

```
select top 200 * 
from table 
order by rowidentifer Desc
```

Thanks

Comment: No. There's no order in a table.

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to have a table with 100,000,000,000,000,000 rows.  If you do, you should have a pretty good DBA that you can talk to.

Comment: Yep. Complete BS. even if each row was tiny at 14 bytes that would be 1400 petabytes of storage for the table.

Comment: And maximum database size in SQL Server is 524.272 petabytes. The minimum row size is 9 bytes so not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a row.identifier that i could use in a table ie set top 200 * from table order by row.identifer Desc

As already stated in the comment's, ***there is not***. The best way is having an identity, timestamp or some other form of identifying the record. Here is an alternative way using `EXCEPT` to get what you need, but the execution plan isn't the best... Play around with it and change as needed.

```
     --testing purposes...
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(FirstName VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @count INT = 0

WHILE (@count <= 12000) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tbl(FirstName)
    SELECT
        'RuPaul ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(5))

    SET @count += 1

END

--adjust how many records you would like, example is 200
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
EXCEPT(SELECT TOP (SELECT COUNT(*) - 200 FROM @tbl) * FROM @tbl)

--faster than above 
DECLARE @tblCount AS INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl) - 200
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
EXCEPT(SELECT TOP (@tblCount) * FROM @tbl)
```

On another note, you could create another `Table Variable` that has an ID and other columns, then you could insert the records you would need. Then you can perform other operations against the table, for example `OrderBy` etc...

***What you could do***

```
 ALTER TABLE TABLENAME
 ADD ID INT IDENTITY
```

This will add another column to the table "ID" and automatically give it an ID. Then you have an identifier you can use...